# Create and fill new columns using values in rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
Dataframe A:

Col1   Col2   Value
 A      X       1
 A      Y       2
 B      X       3
 B      Y       2
 C      X       5
 C      Y       4

Dataframe B:

Col1   
 A
 B
 C
```

What I need is to add to Dataframe B one column for each value in Col2 of Dataframe A (in this case, X and Y), and filling them with the values in column "Value" after having merged the two dataframes on Col1. Here is it:

```
Col1   X    Y
 A     1    2
 B     3    2
 C     5    4
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `df1.pivot(*df1)` works for your example

Answer (score 0):

```
B['X'] = A.loc[A['Col2'] == 'X', 'Value'].reset_index(drop = True)
B['Y'] = A.loc[A['Col2'] == 'Y', 'Value'].reset_index(drop = True)


      Col1  X   Y
   0    A   1   2
   1    B   3   2
   2    C   5   4
```

If you are going to have 100s of distinct values in Col2 then you call the above two lines in a loop, like this:

```
for t in A['Col2'].unique():
    B[t] = A.loc[A['Col2'] == t, 'Col3'].reset_index(drop = True)
    B[t] = A.loc[A['Col2'] == t, 'Col3'].reset_index(drop = True)

B
```

You get the same output:

```
      Col1  X   Y
   0    A   1   2
   1    B   3   2
   2    C   5   4
```

Comment: That's completely not scalable, that is only and example, I have like 100 columns, I don't think I'm gonna write a line for each one of them

Comment: I am assuming you meant 100s of distinct values in 'Col2'.  If my understanding is incorrect then probably you need to make your example more clear.